# TypeError: failed to coerce oracle.sql.DATE to oracle.sql.DATE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, jruby, jboss7.x, jndi

Environment:
  Rails 3.2.11
  JRuby 1.7.2
  activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.4)

Server:
  jboss-as 7.1 standalone, Java 1.6.2

The issue is around a date being sent into a request parameter in valid timestamp format (2013-04-12 08:00:00.000000).  When doing this in rails it throws the error that is in the title which doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

This doesn't happen when I run it in native jruby and java 1.7 though.  Looking for answers to find a work around before I install the later java version on my server.

I was able to get by this issue by switching the connection settings to a connection string instead of JNDI; so suspecting this is a bug somewhere in the jboss layer.

Comment: Could you answer your own question with exactly how you solved it? I'm running into the same problem, but I don't understand "switching the connection settings to a connection string".

Comment: I believe in JBOSS AS there is a setting that you need to update from JNDI to another option. I don't have access to the project any longer.  I can't figure it out.